# Wordpress / PhpStorm / XDebug and plugin_dir_path issues

Tags: php, plugin-development, ide

I am trying to debug a wordpress plugin. I have XDebug working and I am able to use breakpoints and such.

My issue is with the `plugin_dir_url(__FILE__)` call.

It results to `http://192.168.0.18/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/xdebug:/`
It should be `http://192.168.0.18/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/GFTH-BB-Update`

I am guessing it has something to do with the setup of the debugger in PHP Storm, but for the life of me I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. After long hours, I realized I was using JQuery in the .js and not jQuery. The difference one letter cap makes.